# Why was this JSP answer deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer, moderators

I originally found a question I was looking for an answer to, and once I found the solution I added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73964447).

I then realised that question was a duplicate of [an even older one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1082759), so I closed the duplicate and copied the answer (with changes to match the question) over. No other answer on the question has this solution, which is (IMO) the optimal way to do it for versions that support it.

[image]

However, it appears it was deleted by a moderator within three hours. As it was mod-deleted there is nothing I can do except ask here why they did it.

Comment: The mod was handling a "duplicate answer" flag. Seems they chose the wrong way around. (They obviously chose based on time-stamps, which is a reasonable and standard heuristic.) You could have prevented this by following up to delete your original answer on the question you closed as a dupe. I've corrected the situation now.

Comment: @CodyGray thanks. I think it's a bit of an edge case as nobody noticed the duplicate for ten years, and nor did I until the next day.

Comment: I don't see where the edge case comes in.

Comment: @CodyGray there are also other duplicate answers on them that haven't been deleted

Comment: Sure, because they weren't flagged. That's not an edge case, that's the normal case. You can help solve that problem.

Comment: "*As it was mod-deleted there is nothing I can do except ask here why they did it.*" For what it's worth you can also flag the post for moderator attention and ask why it was done or explain why you think it was a mistake. If it was a mistake or if there is a clear better outcome, mods will _usually_ be happy to rectify the situation.

Comment: @TylerH if I flagged it, how would I get a reply?

Comment: @OrangeDog If you request a reply, moderators can send a mod mail, start a private chat with you, or you can just observe your flag page for when it is handled and see if the mods included a custom response there. But if it is just a "oops, we goofed, it has been fixed", a custom-worded reply is not necessarily called for.

Comment: @TylerH there's mod mail? Member for 12 years and I never knew.

Comment: Yep, it would show up as a notification in the inbox and take you to a /users/messages/ URI with a specific value; I think each message endpoint is only visible to mods and the user associated with the mail. It is a way for them to communicate more in-depth things to users when needed, without having to resort to full-on email.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Answering different questions with an identical answer automatically raises a moderator flag. Moderators will then come along and delete all but one answer.

If you feel that questions can be answered with the same answer, answer one of them and vote to close the other as a duplicate. If they don't deserve identical answers then write custom answers for each question.

If you want your moderator deleted answer undeleted, delete your answer on the duplicate first, you can then flag your deleted answer (or in fact any of your posts if you like) to have the answer you want undeleted, explaining that you've deleted the other copy instead.

Comment: That's what I did. I was just coming in to tidy up and found it gone. I don't want to delete the first one until the second is back, because then the correct answer will be nowhere.

Comment: You could ask a moderator to swap the deletion then but they won't permit duplicate answers. I don't expect that having your answer missing for a few hours is going to be world changing though.

Comment: Also, if I might add. Closing/deleting duplicates is one of the cases where ordinary (privileged) users should be able to step in and overrule diamond mod decisions. The side effect of the diamond (or in case of closing, a tag gold badge) is that one's close/delete vote no longer need consensus by several users. So it is easier to slip. And I heard from an inside source that a couple of the moderators are still humans and not yet replaced by bots :)

Comment: (Though keep in mind that mods can _merge_ two duplicates into one, which is sort of rare. In which case regular users probably shouldn't attempt to rollback or it will get messy. In such rare cases where someone disagrees with a merge, then bring it up on meta.)